Парсинг ссылок на плейлисты из постов ВК группы pyhton
Задача - доставать из постов группы ссылки на плейлисты.
У меня есть вот такой код, он может вывести только последнюю ссылку на плейлист, как сделать так чтобы он мог выводить ссылки на все плейлисты, а не только нулевого item? (пока их всего 3, но будет больше)

import requests

token = ''
version = 5.199
domain = ''

list_of_pl = []


#while offest < 1000:
response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get',
                        params={
                            'access_token': token,
                            'v': version,
                            'domain': domain,
                            'count': 100,
                            #'offest': offest


                        }
                        )


data = response.json()['response']['items'][0]['attachments'][0]['link']['url']





добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. попробуйте начать с заголовка.

 data = response.json()['response']['items']
 lst = []
 for el in data:
     lst.append(el['attachments'][0]['link']['url'])

Можно использовать цикл
